# How to make a Hidden layout Visible Using Button Click?

Tags: android, android-layout

Here in this code I have tried some touch screen event

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

    switch (touchevent.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        {
            oldTouchValue = touchevent.getX();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        {
            float currentX = touchevent.getX();
            if (oldTouchValue < currentX  && panel.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {                   
                panel.clearAnimation();
                panel.startAnimation(mAnimHide);
                panel.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
            if (oldTouchValue > currentX  && panel.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
            {
                panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                panel.startAnimation(mAnimShow);
            }
        break;
        }
    }


    return false;
}
```

//when i tried the below its not working

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.onClick:
    }
    if(panel.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
    {
        panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        panel.startAnimation(mAnimShow);
    }
}
```

When I Tried to have to make the Hidden Layout Visible on the Button Click 
The program is not Responding. I have tried enough.

Can anyone please help me? How should we make the action event work ?

Comment: Just a tip.. use panel.isShown() instead of comparing the Visibility.

Comment: try putting `Log.d()` inside your `if` blocks to check whether app gets there

Comment: I have tried using Log.() in my code when it tring to execute the View.INVISIBLE it is returning
Java Null Point Error -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of View.INVISIBLE use class of panel .
for example if panel is instance of TextView :

```
if(panel.getVisibility()==TextView.INVISIBLE)
    {
        panel.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        panel.startAnimation(mAnimShow);
    }
```

Comment: VISIBLE constant is inherited from `View`, so it will not change anything

Comment: I want to visible My Layout named (panel) to visible and invisible mode not any Text view.. can u help me in this ??

Answer (score 1):

Try using the actual int of the id, not R.id.onClick. So if you gave the button an id of 30, for example, use `case 30:`...

Answer (score 0):

```
case R.id.title_call_button:
if(llButtonCallNow.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE){
llButtonCallNow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
    else{
    llButtonCallNow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
break;
```